# Does meditation have and effect on Priming?

Tags: meditation, priming

I’m reading Think Fast And Slow and am learning about the priming effect. Has anyone studied how meditation affects this phenomenon?  Are folks who meditate any less likely to respond to being primed?

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  Can you provide some background on why you think there should be a connection between meditation and priming, and what efforts you have made yourself to find information on the topic?

Comment: I was wondering because my understanding of meditation - obviously, there are many types - is to become more aware of your thoughts. The way I’m reading the book, meditation appears to be an attempt by System 2 to change - or perhaps more quickly come to the aid of - System 1.